# How do I pass quoted parameters to PowerShell Invoke-Command and ScripBlocks?

Tags: powershell

I need to run a ps1 script on a remote computer. The script will be passed a single parameter representing a file name. I have tried many, many different combinations and approaches to passing the parameters to the script block, but I am always getting one error or another **when trying to support spaces in the script name and/or file name**.

*Note: The end result will be running a script on a **REMOTE** computer using the `-ComputerName` parameter to [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6), but for simplicity and testing all the examples run locally.*

Given the sample "remote" script

```
#processFile.ps1
$args[0]     # Just outputs the first parameter passed
```

The following works when there are no spaces in the name

```
$cmd = ".\processFile.ps1"
$fn = "someFile.csv"
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create("$cmd $fn")
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb

# Outputs the correct
someFile.csv
```

However, the following does not work

```
$cmd = ".\processFile.ps1"
$fn = "some File.csv"
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create("$cmd $fn")
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb

# Outputs the incorrect
some
```

Obviously, the file name parameter needs to be escaped and passed as "some File.csv". And this can be done with the following:

```
$cmd = ".\processFile.ps1"
$fn = "some File.csv"
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create("$cmd `"$fn`"")   # Notice the escape $fn parameter
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $sb

# Outputs the correct
some File.csv
```

**BUT**, when I try to extended this space support to the script name, everything falls apart. The following fails

```
$cmd = ".\processFile.ps1"
$fn = "some File.csv"
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create("`"$cmd`" `"$fn`"") # Notice the attempt to escape both parameters
```

with the following exception

```
Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "Unexpected token 'some File.csv' in expression or statement."
```

Everything I have tried, and there have been many, many different approaches, have resulted in something similar. I just cannot seem to get both parameters to be escaped. (Actually, the problem is more than I cannot escape the **first** parameter. Some of my attempts have included nested quotes, single quotes, [ScriptBlock]::Create, { }, $executionContext, etc.

Comment: See also *[Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create(@"
&'$cmd' '$fn'
"@)
```

Comment: That works. Thank you mjolinor. But can you explain what is going on here? I understand that the "&" operator treats the string as a command but how does that apply to the two sets of single quotes for the parameters?

Comment: When you quote it like that, you have to invoke it explicitly, otherwise it's just treated as a string. That really doesn't have anything to do with the single quotes for the parameters - those are to keep the parameters together for the command arguments. Using the here-string just eliminates the need to have to escape or double the quotes. You can put whatever kind of quotes you want, whereever you want them.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone puzzling over the accepted answer by mjolinor, you need to add:

`. $sb`

For it to actually run the script block.

Additionally, a simpler syntax which seems more readable to me is:

```
$cmd = @"
&'$cmd' '$fn'
"@
Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

Comment: I'd always suggest using `&` instead of `.` unless you have a reason to use dot. `&` invokes in a new scope; `.` runs in local scope - so side-effects are more likely.